# Think of sth - meaning in a context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have been trying to understand the usage of "think of" and "think about" for some time and would like to know whether I got it right:

> I am thinking about/of changing a job. What do you think about/of him?

No difference in meaning.

But:

> It is broken, I need to think of a possible fault.

I think here I do not know the fault yet.

> It is broken, I need to think about the problem.

I know the problem already and I am thinking about it/fixing it.

Comment: I am thinking about/of changing a job. What do you think about/of him?

No difference in meaning.

Comment: What does "sth" mean in the title? I'm a native (US Southern) speaker, but have never seen this abbreviation before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To think of something **can mean** to imagine it when it is something that is **not in your mind**. Synonyms would be: come up with, find, discover, drum up, invent, etc.

- I need to **think of** a solution for this problem. [there is not one in my mind; as of now, I have no solution to it.]

To "think about something" **can mean** the thing is **already in (your) mind** but you have not spent any time thinking about it.

- I need to think about that solution to this problem. [in this case a solution is in your mind or has been presented to you and you need to turn it over in your mind.]

These usages fit with the "It is broken, I need to think about the problem/think of a possible fault".

Comment: I suppose most contexts it is used affect **as of** to mean like **from now on**. Interestingly, lots of books guide learners only to the meaning. This is why learners only take it to mean **from now on**.